# Tipsy tooltip is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

In [this page](http://www.designingstudios.com/projects/LSI_Html/detail.html), I have implemented tipsy tooltip, jbgallery two jquery plugins. You can observe tool tip appears when you rollover logo, i have written the same for icons appearing right bottom of the page i.e. (Tag, Facebook, Twitter icons etc...) can any one help me in this please...

Comment: Friends... i tried with another tooltip plugin called "Tip tip" even this have the same issue for logo its coming but not for the icons (-;

Comment: If i remove this alert is coming:
var obj = $("#fullscreen").jbgallery({
 menu  : 'simple',
 style : 'zoom',
 caption  : true,
 slideshow:true, 
 fade: true
}, true);

Comment: Looks like nobody can help you - you need to strip your site right down to its basics, make a really simple html/js site and see if the tooltips still work. then add stuff until it breaks again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are missing the class `.tooltip` on those anchor tags.
Try adding them in and see if it works.
E.g:

```
<a href="#" class="twitter tooltip">twitter</a>
```

****EDIT****
Replace the `$` with `jQuery` and replace `$(function(){` with `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`

****EDIT****
Try this:

```
$('.tooltip').each(function(){
    $(this).tipsy({fade: true});
});
```

Comment: No they are written, for testing i have added only for first block, anyhow i added for all three blocks if you see the source code...

Comment: I think you might be missing the `original-title=""` attribute? If that doesnt work, then move your code to the end of the document, before the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: I have written like this (title="Tag Icon") do you want to replace this like (original-title="Tag Icon")? even though i written like this its not coming, and i given a try by moving these includes to bottom but no chance (-;

Comment: That's weird. Ok, last thing, replace the `$` with `jQuery` and replace `$(function(){` with `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: If i do this, its effecting at logo part, even though its not coming for icons...

Answer (score 0):

and I think the tipsy is reading the original-title attribute in your case to display title.which is missing in (Facebook, Twitter anchor tags.)

I copy this code from your given url. just inspect the elements where I found a little difference in your both places where you added tipsy class.

```
[original-title is available here.]
<a href="#" class="tooltip" original-title="test">
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="" title="">
</a>

[attribute missing original-title here]
<a href="#" class="tooltip twitter" title="Twit Icon">twitter</a>
<a href="#" class="tooltip facebook" title="FB Icon">facebook</a>
```

Comment: Even for the logo i have written just title, i have not written original-title="test"

Comment: Yes you were seeing that original-title because function is calling there but here its not all calling even i tried adding onclick alert for these icons its not working (-;

Answer (score 0):

How are those buttons getting into the DOM? If I run your tooltip activation code on the console:

```
 $('.tooltip').tipsy({fade: true});
```

then it shows me it has added the tipsy function to the icons (and hovering works).

I don't think the DOM is properly loaded when your bit of script runs. Stick it at the bottom of the page, or in a `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` block

Answer (score 0):

When I add a container class(.jbg-caption) in selector, it works. Please try to replace with the following code.

```
$(function() {
$('.tooltip').tipsy({fade: true});
});
```

to

```
$(function() {
$('.jbg-caption a.tooltip').tipsy({fade: true});
});
```

Comment: how about .caption  ? When I check your source code, container class is <div class="caption">.

Comment: please try again $('.jbg-caption a.tooltip') to $('.caption a.tooltip')

Comment: Yes. I tried by editing your javascript in Firebug. It works. But the problem is jbgallery overwrites tooltip CSS when DOM is loaded. That's why you tipsy does not work.

Comment: You can see the logo tooltip coz logo is not in the jbgallery container(<div class="jbgallery").

Comment: Yes thein may be what you said is correct, how to fix this issue then?